# Is it possible to dynamically create items and triggers?

Tags: zabbix

I have a file with list of processes on each hosts. This list is different on each hosts. Can I dynamically create items and triggers in zabbix that check each process on each hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite an open-ended question, but you can use:

- [Zabbix API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/api/reference)
- [XML import](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/xml_export_import)
- [low level discovery (LLD)](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery)